# Google Webmasters Blocked Resources/Robots.txt File?

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt

For some reason Google Webmaster Tools insists that pretty much all js and css resources are blocked on every page of my website and when I try to render my pages in GWT they will only partially render. However, I have placed all of the following in my robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /*.css$
Allow: /*.js$
Allow: /js
Allow: /css
Allow: .js
Allow: .css
Allow: /js/wow
Allow: /js/stellar
```

Can anyone tell me why Google is apparently ignoring commands in my `robots.txt` and how I can correct it?

Comment: Just remove the robots.txt if you're not blocking anything, it is completely unnecessary. Set rules in robots.txt only to block something. [Checkout my blog post about proper way to use robots.txt](https://www.goyllo.com/seo/technical/robots-txt/)

Comment: Thanks, Goyllo, but removing my robots.txt is not a feasible option, as I have other important directives in there. I only added the specific Allow: / directives I mentioned, because Google Webmaster Tools insisted that those file types were being blocked even though they weren't. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: "...were being blocked" - Is GSC (formerly GWT) specifically stating that those resources are being blocked by robots.txt? If you have other directives in robots.txt then maybe it's those that are the problem?

Comment: No, GWT doesn't state that resources are being blocked specifically in my robots.txt file. It is now my belief that this is being caused by above the fold, render blocking, external CSS references in my <head>. What do you think?

Comment: I have been trying to figure out the easiest way to load my CSS asynchronously, but i'm not having much luck. I have been trying to use something called "loadCSS" by filamentgroup, but due to their poor documentation, I can't get it to work. I think i'm going to create a new thread here at Stack Exchange and see if anyone can help me with that and go from there...

Comment: Don't see why your using allow... you only need an allow to override a disallow. It could be that your header response are those particular files are  noindex. Sharing the URL in question does help.

Comment: Thanks, Simon. Since I originally posted this question, I removed all of the Allow directives that I had in my robots.txt. It hasn't made any difference as far as GWT is concerned, though. GWT still insists that pretty much all of my js and css resources are being blocked... Please forgive me for not posting links to my website. For various reasons, I tend to not publicly post links to my website on website help forums. If necessary, I can always PM/email links...

Answer (score 1):

You may have directories in folders that are blocked.
That being the possible case, as you are not mentioning what is blocked, I would use something like this. This way allows you to block subfolders and allow crawling of the folders rooted in the blocked directories.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /blocked-folder/

User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /blocked-folder/css/
Allow: /blocked-folder/js/
```

Updated: Try this based on your code.

---

```
<script> 
<script async src="js/jquery.js">
<script async src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js">
<script async src="js/owl.carousel.min.js">
<script async src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js">

<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> 
<script async src="js/wow/wow.js">

$(document).ready(function () { if ($('html').hasClass('desktop')) { new WOW().init(); } }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Johnny. I have already tried allowing specific directories like that and it didn't work. I'm really thinking it probably has to do with render blocking, above the fold external CSS and js references. I am loading js asynchronously, though, so I don't know why js would be being blocked if that's the case... I'm sorta stumped...

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to load the css and js asynchronously

Comment: So far, I haven't been able to get loadCSS to work properly in order to get my CSS to load asynchronously. loadCSS seems to be what everyone recommends, but as I said, due to its poor documentation I haven't been able to get it to work. No matter how I try to implement it, it breaks my page. Also, I have tried combining my CSS to cut down on rountrips and no matter how I do it, that breaks my pages as well...

Comment: <script async src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script async src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script async src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script async src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
    <script async src="js/wow/wow.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($('html').hasClass('desktop')) {
                new WOW().init();
            }
        });
    </script>

Comment: Above is how I am referencing my js to load it asynchronously. But, according to GWT, those resources are being blocked. It tests perfectly at Google Pagespeed Insights, though...

Comment: Try it without the closing script tags. ie: <script async src="my.js"> not <script async src="my.js"></script>

Comment: @M-n-ISEOGuy look at the update in the answer. That may be your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Johnny. I tried copy/pasting your code in its entirety and it gives me a syntax error on what would be line 2 of your code for some reason...

Comment: Is that where your files are actually located? Mind you I based it on your previous location of files.

Comment: Yes, the file paths are correct... As I mentioned, according to Google Pagespeed Insights, my js is loading asynchronously as is. So, I would presume it's fine the way it is, unless you know something I don't, with regards to not closing the </script> tags after every reference, etc. Asynchronous loading is relatively new to me. I was going to PM you a link to my site, Johnny to perhaps shed a little more light on this for you, but stackexchange doesn't seem to have PM functionality, huh?

Comment: INTERESTING UPDATE: As a test, I referenced all of my external CSS before the </body> instead of in the <head>. Sure enough, the page fully rendered in GWT. However, it breaks the animations on my page, so this isn't a feasible solution for me. Nonetheless, this test confirmed my theory that it is due to the fact that referencing my CSS in the <head> without loading it asynchronously prevents GWT from fully rendering the page. Interestingly, I compared page load speed and it made no difference whatsoever whether the CSS references is above the fold or not. Same exact results both ways...

Comment: RE:INTERESTING UPDATE: Just as another follow-up in case it might help someone else in the future... I removed the async from all of my js references and simply removed all of my js references from the <head> and placed then at </body> along with all of my css references and that fixed my animations as well. All of this did increase my Google Pagespeed "score" by a few points (for both mobile and pc), but did not technically increase my page speed load times according to https://www.webpagetest.org/.

Comment: Further testing shows that this did not necessarily solve my rendering problem with GWT as it turns out. It appears that sometimes everything will render and other times it won't. I believe that is probably because of the Wow animations that I have on pretty much everything on the page. All of my graphics always render. It's just the text (wrapped with Wow animations) that will seldom render. I feel it is most likely because of the delay of the animations. GWT probably renders the whole page faster than the animations load the text. None of this affects SEO, so i'm putting it out of my mind...